# Custom field data input wenzhixin/bootstrap-table

Tags: bootstrap-table

[image]

Hi! I want custom field data, because I have many arrays in one array.
I try using `field: 'LeftNavigation.Title'` but it didn't work.

Comment: Please share code, not pictures: see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/e3nk137y/18183/ please help me!!

Answer (score 0):

You can't using multi Array data in field 
Maybe you should choose another solution for this

Suggest : Create Leftnavigation Field , when click on this field it's show a second table show data from Leftnavigation array